# Filter category in Firebase Image Label

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

Is it possible to filter FirebaseVisionImageLabels **only from one category** using **Firebase Vision Cloud Image Labeler**? Or how can I get a category from ouput FirebaseVisionImageLabel object?

For example, I just need to detect object from category **Food**, for the purposes of my app, I know that I am not interested in objects from any other category.

```
text = Yellow | entityId = /m/088fh   // this is unnecessary
text = Meyer lemon | entityId = /m/04klfb
text = Citron | entityId =  /m/02054x
text = Lemon | entityId = /m/09k_b
text = Citrus | entityId =  /m/0dqb5
```

Categories are mentioned here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/label-images

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that functionality is not available in the API. You will have to filter the results on your end from the response received.

Comment: And can I somehow get a category from entity ID?